# RestApi call through iron-ajax of polymer

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-elements

I am developing a polymer app and I want to make a call to the RestApi.
this is the how the request body is

```
{
    "languageId": Presently English is the only supported language. Always 1, 
    "productCode":"Medicus",
    "timeZoneName":"Time zone name of device. For e.g. Asia/Calcutta",
    "timeZoneOffset": Time zone offset from UTC in milliseconds. For e.g. IST = 19800000,
    "user":{
     "firstName":"First name of the user",
     "lastName":"Last name of the user",
     "middleName":"Middle name of the user",
     "password":"Password provided by the user",
     "userTypeId":2 = Doctor, 3 = User,
     "fields":[
         {
            "Id":1,
            "values":["Mobile number provided by the user”]
         }
     ]
    }
}
```

i am not getting the proper idea of how i should specify these parameters in the  params='{}' of iron-ajax element.

Comment: For starters, your JSON is invalid. See http://jsonlint.com and paste your code there; you will see what's invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put something like this in your template (I am assuming POST to your rest API, since you said `body` in your question. If its GET replace `body=` with `params=`

```
<iron-ajax
       id="fetchday"
       url="/api/fetchday"
       handle-as="json"
       content-type="application/json"
       method="POST"
       body="[[params]]"
       last-response="{{results}}"
       on-response="_gotData"
       on-error="_error"></iron-ajax>
```

And in your polymer element properties

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-element'
  properties: {
    params: {
     type: Object
    } 
  },
  _someFunction: function() {
    this.params = //ASSIGN YOUR JSON OBJECT TO PARAMS HERE
    this.$.fetchday.generateRequest();
  },
  _gotData: function(e) {
    //response data is in both this.results and e.detail.response
 },
 _error: function() {
 }
});
```

Comment: but now i am getting 502 proxy error  do i need to perform JSON.stringify on params and then send it to body or will it do itself considering the content type

Comment: You provide a Javascript Object to this.params in above example.  I think its the `handle-as="json"` that tells iron ajax how to encode it in the body

Comment: is it not possible to make a RestApi call from localhost??

Comment: thank you @akc42 for the answer the problem was with the json format its  resolved.